# Disable autocomplete in C#

Tags: winforms

I have the following problem with AutoComplete feature in ComboBox (DropDown). My settings for combo:

AutoCompleteMode: AutoCompleteMode.None

AutoCompleteSource: AutoCompleteSource.None

DropDownStyle: ComboBoxStyle.DropDown

Issue is - 
It completes the text from database

Can anyone help to deal with this?What am I missing?

Comment: When searched first , auto complete is enabled.However if text is cleared and typed again, Auto complete is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the AutoCompleteCustomSource properties.

Comment: AutoCompleteSource is set to None, So AutoCompleteSource would be optional.Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is this:
EnableAutoComplete = false;
Example:

```cs
    *c#*

    cmbOrderEvasion.EnableAutoComplete = false;
```

```
*dotnet*
cmbOrderEvasion->EnableAutoComplete = false;
```

**Warning:**
Need write manually without Intellsense because Intelsense not suggest ever.